# Unable to POST to local webserver using ESP8266 and AT Commands

Tags: php, post, raspberry-pi3, esp8266, at-command

I'm trying to send data to a local webserver running on Apache2 on a raspberry pi 3. The IP address is 192.168.0.16. I'm going to use a TIVA-C Launchpad to send POST requests to the server using a ESP8266-01 wifi module, however, before implementing everything I wanted to try and see if inputing the AT commands manually to the ESP8266-01 through UART (Using an FTDI and the arduino serial monitor) would work. At the end of the commands, the ESP returns:

```
> 
busy s...

Recv 180 bytes

SEND OK
CLOSED
```

But the database in phpMyAdmin never updates. What could be the matter?

This is the sequence of AT commands that I have tried so far but to no avail.

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.0.16",80
CONNECT

OK

AT+CIPSEND=162

OK

(I send the following POST request all in a single line)
POST /index.php HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host: 192.168.0.16\r\n
Accept:*/*\r\nContent-Length: 40\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
\r\n
idSensor=16555&ch1=1&ch2=0&ch3=0&ch4=1

>
busy s...

Recv 162 bytes
SEND OK
CLOSED
```

This is the code in my web server

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"");
$idSensor = 0;
$ch1 = 0;
$ch2 = 0;
$ch3 = 0;
$ch4 = 0;
//print_r($_POST);
if($_POST){
    $idSensor = $_POST['idSensor'];
    $ch1 = $_POST['ch1'];
    $ch2 = $_POST['ch2'];
    $ch3 = $_POST['ch3'];
    $ch4 = $_POST['ch4'];
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","admin","admin4321", "Parqueo-matic");
    if(!$conexion){
        echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL.".PHP_EOL;
        echo "errno de depuración: ". mysqli_connect_errno().PHP_EOL;
        echo "error de depuración: ". mysqli_connect_error().PHP_EOL;

    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO `Datos` (`ID`, `Hora`, `ID_Sensor`, `P1`, `P2`, `P3`, `P4`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$idSensor', '$ch1', '$ch2', '$ch3', '$ch4');";
        mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        echo "Receiving data";

    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","admin","admin4321", "Parqueo-matic");
if(!$conexion){
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL.".PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: ". mysqli_connect_errno().PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: ". mysqli_connect_error().PHP_EOL;
}else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `Datos` ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
}
mysqli_close($conexion);

header("refresh: 1");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>

        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='utf-8'/>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
        <title>PMatic</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </head>

    <body class="container">
        <br>
        <h1><strong>Parqueo-Matic</strong></h1>
        <br>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID Sensor</th>
                    <th>Parqueo 1</th>
                    <th>Parqueo 2</th>
                    <th>Parqueo 3</th>
                    <th>Parqueo 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                      echo "<tr>
                                <td>".$row['ID_Sensor']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['P1']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['P2']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['P3']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['P4']."</td>
                           </tr>";       

                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>

    </body>

</html>
```

Is there any way to debug or know why my POST request is not producing any change in the database? Thank you

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Instead of opening and closing a new connection to the database each time you're making a new query, just open it once and reuse the same connection through out the request instead. Connections are costly so avoid making extra if you don't need to.

Comment: When making your INSERT, use [mysqli_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if the query failed. If it did, you should log the error message. You should also log the contents of `$_POST` to see what you get. You can also use something like Postman to test your index.php-file.

Comment: Thank you! I'm really new to this. How exactly can I log the contents of $_POST? Also, I tried to reuse the connection but after some time the ESP seems to shut down the connection automatically